# Python Faster way of updating dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to test buying and selling of three different stocks.  I created a class that I plan to plug into an AI system and try to find a strategy.  This currently works.  You can buy [symbol], sell[symbol], and next to just proceed.  Some of the functions take too long. I believe here is a faster and more Python-y way of doing this.  My background is JavaScript.

I am using a dataframe to store trades.  Open trades have no closeTimeStamp.  profit is sell_price - buy_price for closed trades or profit is sell_price - current_quote for open trades (that are short) profit is current_quote - buy_price for open trades that are long.  After I update the holdings_with_quotes I can just sum the profit column and I get the current value of open and closed trades.

```
    self.trades = pd.DataFrame(columns=['symbol', 'buy_price', 'sell_price', 'current_quote', 'openTimeStamp', 'closeTimeStamp', 'profit', 'multiplier'])
```

This function is what is taking so much time.

```
  def update_holdings_with_quotes(self):
    start = time.time()
    if self.current_contracts > 0:
      quotes = self.quotes
      for symbol in ['/ES', '/NQ', '/YM']:
      # for symbol in self.trades['symbol']:
        current_price = self.quotes.loc[symbol]['lastPriceInDouble']
        multiplier = self.quotes.loc[symbol]['futureMultiplier']
        self.trades.loc[self.trades['closeTimeStamp'].isnull() & (self.trades['symbol'] == symbol), 'current_quote'] = current_price
        self.trades.loc[self.trades['closeTimeStamp'].isnull() & (self.trades['symbol'] == symbol) & (self.trades['action'] == Actions.BUY), 'profit'] =  (current_price - self.trades['buy_price']) * multiplier
        self.trades.loc[self.trades['closeTimeStamp'].isnull() & (self.trades['symbol'] == symbol) & (self.trades['action'] == Actions.SELL), 'profit'] =  (self.trades['sell_price'] - current_price)  * multiplier

      self.current_value = self.initial_value + self.trades['profit'].sum()
      self.current_gain = self.current_value - self.initial_value
    print("update_holdings_with_quotes time: {}".format(time.time() - start))
```

Basically I am looping through the three quotes and setting values in my dataframe if the trade has no closeTimeStamp a.k.a. the trade is still open.  I tried using an array of static symbols, but that didn't speed things up.

I could use something other than a dataframe.  I just used it because I thought it would be helpful.

*** I edited the function based on a suggestion to use two dataframes instead of one. One for open trades, and one for closed.  That didn't help much.

```
  def update_holdings_with_quotes(self):
    start = time.time()
    if self.current_contracts > 0:
      quotes = self.quotes
      for symbol in ['/ES', '/NQ', '/YM']:
      # for symbol in self.trades['symbol']:
        current_price = self.quotes.loc[symbol]['lastPriceInDouble']
        multiplier = self.quotes.loc[symbol]['futureMultiplier']
        self.open_trades.loc[(self.open_trades['symbol'] == symbol), 'current_quote'] = current_price
        self.open_trades.loc[(self.open_trades['symbol'] == symbol) & (self.open_trades['action'] == Actions.BUY), 'profit'] =  (current_price - self.open_trades['buy_price']) * multiplier
        self.open_trades.loc[(self.open_trades['symbol'] == symbol) & (self.open_trades['action'] == Actions.SELL), 'profit'] =  (self.open_trades['sell_price'] - current_price)  * multiplier

      self.current_value = self.initial_value + self.open_trades['profit'].sum() + self.closed_trades['profit'].sum()
      self.current_gain = self.current_value - self.initial_value
      # self.logger.info('initial_value={} current_value={} current_contracts={}'.format(self.initial_value, self.current_value, self.current_contracts))
      self.check_status()
    print("update_holdings_with_quotes time: {}".format(time.time() - start))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the part where it gets slow:

```
    self.trades.loc[self.trades['closeTimeStamp'].isnull() & (self.trades['symbol'] == symbol), 'current_quote'] = current_price
    self.trades.loc[self.trades['closeTimeStamp'].isnull() & (self.trades['symbol'] == symbol) & (self.trades['action'] == Actions.BUY), 'profit'] =  (current_price - self.trades['buy_price']) * multiplier
    self.trades.loc[self.trades['closeTimeStamp'].isnull() & (self.trades['symbol'] == symbol) & (self.trades['action'] == Actions.SELL), 'profit'] =  (self.trades['sell_price'] - current_price)  * multiplier
```

In particular asking multiple times every loop to look through the whole "trades" DataFrame just for indexing with:

```
self.trades['closeTimeStamp'].isnull()
self.trades['symbol'] == symbol
```

A stratight forward solution would be to split your DataFrame `trades` into two `closed_trades` and `open_trades`. The latter should be significantly smaller over time and speed up the look up tremendously. As your tracked stocks grow it might be sensible to further split this among symbols through subclassing.

An alternative would be to track your indices of open positions in an array. Each time you add a trade, just add `maxIndex+1` to your array. If you close a trade, drop the index from the list. Just make sure to not reindex.

```
import numpy as np
ix_open = np.array([...])
ix_closed = np.array([...])

# after closing a few trades:
ix_open = np.setdiff1d(ix_open, ix_closed)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I tried splitting it into two dataframes.  I am only working with 60 quotes or rows max and splitting it didn't help much.  I went from 1.7 seconds to run through the whole program to 1.6.  It was a slight improvement, but not as much as I had hoped.